# apt-get updating to new package

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and have installed cmake, but the version included is only 2.8. Minimum version that I require is 3.0.2 for my project ,so how can I use 'apt-get' to install a newer version? Or do I have to install it manually, which kind of eliminates the purpose of having a package manager.

Same goes for eclipse v3.8 and I need v4.4 (or at least v4.x).

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get update` and then trying to do `sudo apt-get install cmake`? Apt-get should also update an existing installation if there is a newer one available. However you may have to update your sources.

Comment: I did update, but it insists that cmake is the newes version.

Comment: It is the newest version for 14.04, you want the latest software in repo, you need the latest OS. "Or do I have to install it manually, which kind of eliminates the purpose of having a package manager." No it does not, it is up to the develpoer to add there apps to the repos NOT the ubuntu devs, go complain there. Also there is an .sh installer right on there website, how hard did you even look ? https://cmake.org/download/ as for eclipse, same thing, right there on there website https://eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: @DavidFoerster The problem is there are no backports neither for `cmake`nor for `eclipse` (and `eclipse` in Wily doesn't go past 3.8 regardless)

Comment: I installed Eclipse now locally and removed it from my package. For cmake I'll try now the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CMake 3.0.2` is shipped with Ubuntu 15.04. It happens that versions from new releases are made available to older releases via 'backports'.

The backports for Trusty can be found at the [Ubuntu package site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-backports/).

Unfortunately, `CMake` is not in the official backport repository. However, I found several [PPAs at Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=cmake) offering `CMake>=3` for Trusty. For example the PPA

- by Nathan Osman offers up-to-date builds (`3.2.2` at the time of writing)

  [https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/ubuntu/cmake-3.x](https://launchpad.net/%7Egeorge-edison55/+archive/ubuntu/cmake-3.x)
- by Jan Henke offers a backport of version `3.0.2`

  [https://launchpad.net/~jhe/+archive/ubuntu/cmake-backport](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejhe/+archive/ubuntu/cmake-backport)

Choose a repo depending on your need to always get very recent versions or not. Add it with the usual

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<...>/<...>
```

do `sudo apt-get update` and you should be offered the newer version.

**Eclipse:** Apparently since the new "Mars" release of Eclipse, the developers offer a [proper installer](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux) for Linux/OSX/Windows. I would remove the old Eclipse version from the Ubuntu repos and try this one.
<strike>I have not tried this out myself!</strike> I tried it out and it works very nicely. By default it installs to your home-folder, so it's very easy to get rid of if you don't like it.